# Typescript/React - destructuring from this.state throws error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the following method in one of my React components:

```
getRandomColor(){
  const { colors }: { colors: any } = this.state;
  return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}
```

However, typescript is throwing me an error at the destructuring statement, and I have no idea why:

> Type 'Readonly<{}>' is not assignable to type '{ colors: any; }'.
>     Property 'colors' is missing in type 'Readonly<{}>'.

Can someone tell me why? I definitely set `this.state.colors` in the constructor and even if I didn't, I'm not entirely sure why it would throw me that error.

Comment: so you're [trying to do this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20State%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20colors%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0Aconst%20state%3A%20State%20%3D%20%7B%20colors%3A%20%7B%20green%3A%20'green'%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20%7B%20colors%20%7D%3A%20%7B%20colors%3A%20any%20%7D%20%3D%20state%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.write(colors.green)%3B)? seems to work, maybe your state isn't quite setup right.

Comment: I think I may need to assign a type interface to the `this.state = ` statement in the constructor. For some reason I assumed the types would be automatically inferred

Comment: it telling you Readonly is a type seems odd to me. didn't think readonly was a type. that or i'm misunderstanding the error message.

Comment: It just seems that it can't find find a type for the color variable in `this.state` - when I changed the line to `const colors = this.state.colors` the error became: `Property 'colors' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'`. But now the question is how do I define that type?

Comment: and why is it readonly? heh. well, it should be readonly, and modified using setState, so i guess that kinda makes sense.

Comment: @KevinB yup - if I'm not mistaken the component state is immutable? Anyways I worked it out and posted the answer. Thanks for being my rubber duck :)

Answer (score 1):

In TypeScript, class properties need type definitions:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

`this.state` being a property of my component class also needed that type definition:

```
interface State{
  colors: string[];
};

class ColorPicker extends React.Component {
  state: State;
  //...
}
```

After I added this, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for destructuring is like this:

```
const { colors } = this.state;
```

This assumes there is a `this.state.colors`

Comment: My syntax is TypeScript - the `const { colors }` is the ES6 destructuring part, and `: { colors: any }` is the TypeScript type declaration for that variable: https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2015/11/13/typing-destructured-object-parameters-in-typescript